# Kibana service is running but can not access via browser to console

Tags: elasticsearch, debian, logstash, kibana

Good afternoon community,

I have the following problem, which will surely be silly, but I do not give with the key. I have a Debian 9 machine where I have ELK installed (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana). It has been configured as it comes in the documentation. The installation versions correspond to the 6.x.

The services start correctly each and every one of them, the problem is when accessing the Kibana console through port 5601, when I access the browser and enter the url : 5601, I get a message that tells me the following "Kibana server is not ready yet"

I have not configured much more than what the official documentation says, so I do not understand why I do not lift the console to start configuring it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I remember right, kibana uses elasticsearch to store a few things, maybe check if elasticsearch is running and check the configuration you've provided to kibana.

Comment: As @baudsp mentioned, kibana needs an elasticsearch instance running to connect to. Please provide us the following information:
elasticsearch.yml, kibana.yml and the log messages from kibana (should be in /var/log/kibana.log orout of journalctl)